# Pulling data from database into different database [Spring Boot]

Tags: mysql, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I have an unusual problem. My Spring Boot application is using a database located on a Docker container (PostgreSQL 11). I have to pull the initialization data from another database (MySQL 5.5.60) only once and save this on my database. The current application contains many Entities. Is it possible to get the data by repository only for the specific entity? Many examples I see on the Internet present how to use multiple databases but only for two entities (creates two different configs for each entity) and I understand this like I have to create a new config for each of my current existing entities? Is there a way to create config only for one repository and the rest of the repositories will use the default database.

Maybe there is a better way to collect the data without creating different configs if I have to do this only once?

Comment: If it is only one time operation when starting up the application why can't you simply establish a DB connection, fetch data from other DB using JdbcTemplate and populate in default DB? Configuring a DataSource pool for one time operation is unnecessary from memory usage point of view.

Comment: I think you have to create multiple datasource beans. you can refer this blog : https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-multiple-databases